# Remove pattern in first occurence from right to left in file name in bash

Tags: bash

Say I have a string file name `aa.bb.cc.xx.txt` 
I would like to remove the first content between . and . (remove .xx) before the .txt to have `aa.bb.cc.txt`.

I don't want to use rev, cut and rev because this uses 3 commands

```
echo 'aa.bb.cc.xx.rpm' |rev | cut -d '.' --complement -s -f 2 |rev
```

Is there any better solution by using bash?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the file ends with `.txt`, you can remove that as well, then put it back on.

```
$ oldname=aa.bb.cc.xx.txt
$ echo "${oldname%.*.txt}.txt"
aa.bb.cc.txt
```

`%.*.txt` removes the shortest string matching the pattern `.*.txt` (in this case, `.xx.txt`).

If the extension could be an arbitrary string, you can save it by removing everything *but* the extension as a prefix, then restoring it.

```
$ echo "${oldname%.*.*}.${oldname##*.}"
```

`##*.` removes the longest matching prefix ending in `.`, in this case `aa.bb.cc.xx.`. Both operators require removing the `.` that delimits the matched prefix or suffix, which is why you need to add it back explicitly between the two expansions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sed` as follows:

```
$ echo "aa.bb.cc.xx.txt" | sed "s/.[a-zA-Z].txt/txt/g"
aa.bb.cc.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a general `sed` solution that works on any extension, you can do:

```
$ echo 'aa.bb.cc.xx.rpm' | sed 's/[^.]*\.\([^.]*\)$/\1/'
aa.bb.cc.rpm
```